# MaxDiff problem of hackerrank - optimize code as its giving timeout

Tags: arrays, optimization, sub-array

Below is my implementation for [maxdiff](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/iitvsiit2/challenges/maxdiff/problem) problem on hackerrank.
It passed all testcases except 1 where its giving timeout.
Help me optimize it.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        int n = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        if(n==0 || n==1)
            System.out.println(0);;
        String s=scanner.nextLine();
        String ar[] = s.split("\\s+");
        int[] a=new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            a[i]=Integer.parseInt(ar[i]);
        }
        int max, min;
        long sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            max=a[i];
            min=a[i];

            for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(a[j]>max)
                    max=a[j];
                if(a[j]<min)
                    min=a[j];

                sum+=max-min;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Failing testcase is too big to attach here.

Comment: When n == 0, shouldn’t you return from main after printing 0 ? Otherwise the program will continue by trying to read values. When n == 1, you should read one value, print 0 and return as well. Another problem is that the instruction sum += max-min, should be after the for loop, not in its body.

Answer (score 0):

I see one problem.

The problem is with handling n == 0 and n == 1. You should return after printing 0: Here is what you should have.

```java
if (n==0 || n==1) {
    if (n==1)
        scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(0);
    return;
}
```

Comment: I agree regarding n==0 and n==1 but if u take out sum of the nested loop so you think still you will get the right result? Won't you miss numbers?

Comment: @nanosoft Oops, my bad. You are right. I checked the example again and you are right. I'll remove that from my answer.